# Am I using distinct() right?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to create a simple app to display a list of database records. Said data is loaded in bulk from a csv by means of csvimport. The csv file I'm loading has several thousands of records, but for this test theres one column (municipio, it means *city*) which has the same value for all of them.

In an index view I'm using for tests, I want to display the number of (different) cities loaded, and then a list of said cities.

This is in my views.py

```
def index(request):

    num_municipios = DireccionEnCobertura.objects.values_list('municipio').distinct().count()
    municipios = DireccionEnCobertura.objects.values('municipio').distinct()
    return (render (request, 'index.html', context={'num_municipios':num_municipios, 'municipios':municipios}))
```

this is in my index.html

```
<ul>
    <li><strong>Municipios:</strong> {{ num_municipios }}</li>

  </ul>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <td>Municipios Incluidos</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for municipio in municipios.distinct() %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{ municipio.municipio }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

and this is the model

```
class DireccionEnCobertura(models.Model):
    gescal17 = models.CharField(max_length=17, help_text="")
    municipio = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="")
    tipo_via = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="")
    nombre_via = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="")
    numero = models.CharField( max_length=5, help_text="", null=True)
    cod_postal = models.CharField( max_length=5, help_text="")
    uuii = models.CharField( max_length=5, help_text="", null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["tipo_via", "nombre_via", "numero"]



    def __str__(self):
        return self.municipio + " " + self.tipo_via + " " + self.nombre_via + " " + str( self.numero )

    def googleMapsLink(self):
        link = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query="
        return link  + self.tipo_via.replace(" ", "%20") + "%20" + self.nombre_via.replace(" ", "%20") + "%2C" + str( self.numero ) + "%2C" + self.cod_postal + "%2C" +  self.municipio
```

the "municipio" field is the one I've called "city" for clarity's sake.

I've checked the csv file up and down, I've copied the value from the first cell to the rest of the column to make sure there wasn't some hidden character making it different somewho, but I still get

> num_municipios = 1

(which is correct) but

> for municipio in municipios

shows hundreds and hundreds of the same thing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a default `ordering`. From [the documentation for `distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct):

> If you use a `values()` query to restrict the columns selected, the columns used in any `order_by()` (or default model ordering) will still be involved and may affect uniqueness of the results.

Since you don't care about the order for this purpose, just [remove the ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by).

> If you don’t want any ordering to be applied to a query, not even the default ordering, call `order_by()` with no parameters.

Like so:

```
municipios = DireccionEnCobertura.objects.order_by().values('municipio').distinct()
```